# How to save img loaded by caffe.io.load_image

Tags: python, numpy, caffe, pycaffe

```
k = 1
for k in range(1,21):
    img = caffe.io.load_image(imgpath + str(k) + '.png')
    result = caffe.io.load_image(imgpath + str(k) + '.png')
    patch_dim = 33
    h = (patch_dim - 1) / 2
    for i in range(patch_dim / 2, img.shape[0] - patch_dim / 2):
        for j in range(patch_dim / 2, img.shape[1] - patch_dim / 2):
            net.blobs['data'].data[...] = transformer.preprocess('data', img[i-h:i+h+1, j-h:j+h+1])
            out = net.forward()
            if out['prob'][0][1] >= 0.8:
                result[i][j][0] = 1
    result.save(resultpath + str(k) + ".png")
    k = k + 1
```

here is the code.I load the image use caffe.io.load_img and want to save it after processing,but there is an error:

> ```
> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'save'
> ```

how to save it,please？

Comment: convert `result` to `uint8` before using `PIL` to save it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PIL` instead to save the image. I don't think `caffe` has any method exposed for saving the image.

**Edit** - Yeah, [there's no](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/python/caffe/io.py) function to save image.

```
from PIL import Image 
img = Image.fromarray(result.astype('uint8')) # convert image to uint8
img.save(path+'.png')
```

Comment: I‘ve tried but Image seems can't handle that data type. I.ve paste the error in my question.

Comment: @StalkerMuse Did you try converting it to uint8?